# Regex: How to match a string multiple times while capturing groups differently

Tags: python, regex, regex-group

I have a string that looks something like this:

`AB`

And I want to capture it using a regex that looks like this:

`(?P<GRP1>(A|D))?(?P<GRP2>(A|C))?B`

Is there a python function that would produce two matches for the string? The first by capturing `A` as a part of `GRP1` and the second by capturing it as a part of `GRP2`?

I tried functions like `re.fullmatch` and `re.findall` but all of them only capture `A` as part of `GRP1`.

The function I'm looking for would produce one match when matching against `DB` or `CB`, but two matches for `AB`, one for each group that `A` can belong to.

Answer (score 0):

That is not what regex is designed for. Regex is about matching a span of the input against a pattern. So any span of the input is either a match or it is not. The span is "consumed" in the process, that is, the same span cannot match the pattern twice. On the other hand a pattern can match multiple non-overlapping spans, which is what `findall` is about.

There are some advanced regex technics that do not consume any characters while matching (lookahead/lookbehind), but those inherently also do not capture any input which makes them useless for you.

Usually this is the point where one should start thinking about not using regex or atleast not using *only* regex.

I see to possible solutions

1. Use two regex patterns, one for each GRP. This would make the overall result a tupple representing 0-2 matches representing either none, GPR1, GPR2 or GPR1+GPR2
2. Use one regex pattern but restructure it like this `(?P<GRP1>(D))?(?P<GRP2>(C))?(?P<GRP1_2>(A))?B` i.e. have a separate group for each thing that may occure. With `GRP1_2` representing the GRP1&GRP2 case. So, for example if your goal is to count the GRP1 and GRP2 matches then you would count GRP1_2 to both.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah for sure:

You can use lookahead:

```
(?=(?P<GRP1>(A|D)))(?=(?P<GRP2>(A|C)))\wB
```

Which is basically zero width assertion - meaning it will capture the wanted group but not take space in the actual match.

https://regex101.com/r/o1petz/1

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for group matching -- groups are made based on "()"

```
import re

a = re.search('(.*)(.xlsx)', 'doc.xlsx')

print(a.group(1))
print(a.group(2))
```

this example will print

```
doc
.xlsx
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to capture 2 times `A` in `AB`, and just a single capture for `D` or `C` in `DB` or `CB` you can use a capture group in a lookahead assertion and make the capture group optional.

```
(?=(?P<GRP1>[AD])?)(?=(?P<GRP2>[AC])?)[A-Z]B
```

**Explanation**

- `(?=` Positive lookahead

  - `(?P<GRP1>[AD])?` Named group *GRP1*, optionallymatch either `A` or `D`
- `)` Close the lookahead
- `(?=` Positive lookahead

  - `(?P<GRP2>[AC])?` Named group *GRP2*, optionally match either `A` or `C`
- `)` Close the lookahead
- `[A-Z]B` Match a char A-Z followed by `B`

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/GdUHIA/1) and a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/DaEXyk).

```
pattern = r"(?=(?P<GRP1>[AD])?)(?=(?P<GRP2>[AC])?)[A-Z]B"
s = "AB\nDB\nCB"
matches = re.finditer(pattern, s)

for _, m in enumerate(matches, start=1):
    print([g for g in m.groups() if g])
```

Output

```
['A', 'A']
['D']
['C']
```

---

If you don't want to match any char followed by `B` but only `A` `C` or `D`

```
(?=(?P<GRP1>[AD])?)(?=(?P<GRP2>[AC])?)[ACD]B
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Gx28tH/1)